# MVVM vs. WCF Data Service

Tags: wcf, mvvm

I am developing a WPF application and need help in understanding which pattern would be better for data operations.  Should I implement an MVVM solution or should I use WCF Data Services?  What are the pros and cons for each.

Answer (score 4):

I think you don't understand what is MVVM? And what is WCF Data Services?
MVVM is an pattern architecture while WCF Data Services is framework delivered by .Net platform to help you exposing your data via REST architecture using the OData protocol.

In additional, MVVM stands for Model - View - View-Model, and you can use MVVM and WCF Data Services in the same application.  Your WCF Data Services will just represent your Model (the first M in MVVM)

Comment: [Here is a demo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474212/Zombie-Explorer-A-N-Tier-application-from-top-to-b) app tying MVVM, WCF and other goodies together. In fairness I haven't had time to test drive it yet but am meaning to, as the author tends to produce quality material. Cheers